# Looking for STT and TTS API

Tags: speech-recognition, text-to-speech, speech-to-text

I'm looking for API with Text-to-Speech, and, more importantly, Speech-to-Text (I need it to return string).
Preferably it should be on C++, C#, Java or Python, but that's not crucial
And it would be great if it'd have its own database, so there'd be no need in long learning

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, kindly visit [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to understand the type of questions asked in this community. We will be only able to help if you provide us with a lead to begin with. Kindly modify your code to include your working as well. Thanks.

Comment: You can check here https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/882375/python-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b8-offline/882650#882650

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked on a lot of Text to speech and speech to text projects. This is for Python by the way. Most apis have bad free plans and decent paid ones. Google text to speech is very good and well organized on the google cloud. https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech For your speech to text, I would use the built in "SpeechRecgonition" api in the Pycharm interpreter.